# AWS Terraform postgresql provider: SSL is not enabled on the server

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a database in the created postgres RDS in AWS with *postgresql* provider. The terraform script i have created is as following:

```
    resource "aws_db_instance" "test_rds" {
  allocated_storage        = "" # gigabytes
  backup_retention_period  = 7   # in days
  engine                   = ""
  engine_version           = ""
  identifier               = ""
  instance_class           = ""
  multi_az                 = ""
  name                     = ""
  username                 = ""
  password                 = ""
  port                     = ""
  publicly_accessible      = "false"
  storage_encrypted        = "false"
  storage_type             = ""
  vpc_security_group_ids   = ["${aws_security_group.test_sg.id}"]
  db_subnet_group_name     = "${aws_db_subnet_group.rds_subnet_group.name}"
}
```

The postgresql provider is as following:

```
# Create databases in rds
provider "postgresql" {

  alias           = "alias"
  host            = "${aws_db_instance.test_rds.address}"
  port            =  5432
  username        = 
  password        = 
  database        = 
  sslmode         = "disable"

}

# Create user in rds
resource "postgresql_role" "test_role" {
  name             = 
  replication      = true
  login            = true
  password         = 
}

# Create database rds
resource "postgresql_database" "test_db" {
  name              = testdb
  owner             = "${postgresql_role.test_role.name}"
  lc_collate        = "C"
  allow_connections = true
  provider          = "postgresql.alias"
}
```

Anyway i keep retrieving
**Error: Error initializing PostgreSQL client: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: pq: SSL is not enabled on the server**

Note: the empty fields are already filled and the RDS is successfully created, the problem rises when trying to create the database in the rds with the postgresql provider.

Comment: ok found the problem which has nothing to do iwth SSL enablement. I have to set the provider on the **postgresql_role** too as: 
`provider          = "postgresql.alias"`

Comment: In my case, the my `host` variable was wrong, having an empty string.

Answer (score 8):

We ran into this issue as well, and the problem was that the password was not defined. It seems that we will get the SSL is not enabled error when it has problems connecting. We also had the same problem when the db host name was missing. You will need to make sure you define all of the fields needed to connect in Terraform (probably database and username too).

Comment: This is kind of what was happening to me. Add to the list checking you've specified the provider on the resource as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring there was a password set for the postgres user and disabled sslmode, did it for me

`sslmode = "disable"`